# Custom implementation of ```ArrayMap``` Using ```AbstractMap``` JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract, implementation

I am trying to implement an `ArrayMap<K,V>` based on an `AbstractMap<K, V>` but I don't know why my `entrySet()` should return and I have tried to make it return something using `AbstractSet` but it really doesn't like my Arraylist of entries...

```
public class ArrayMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V> {
    private Set<Entry<K, V>> entries = null;
    private ArrayList<ArrayMapEntry<K, V>> list;

    public ArrayMap() {
        list = new ArrayList<ArrayMapEntry<K, V>>();
    }

    public ArrayMap(int initialCapacity) {
        list = new ArrayList<ArrayMapEntry<K, V>>(initialCapacity);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        if (entries == null) {
            entries = new AbstractSet<Entry<K, V>>() {
                @Override
                public void clear() {
                    list.clear();
                }

                @Override
                public Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
                    return list.iterator();
                }

                @Override
                public int size() {
                    return list.size();
                }
            };
        }
        return entries;
    }
    static class ArrayMapEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
        protected K key;
        protected V value;

        public ArrayMapEntry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public V setValue(V v) {
            value = v;
            return v;
        }

        public String toString() { return key + " : " + value; }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof ArrayMapEntry)) {
                return false;
            }
            ArrayMapEntry e = (ArrayMapEntry) o;

            return (key == null? e.getKey() == null : key.equals(e.getKey()))
                    && (value == null ? e.getValue() == null : value.equals(e.getValue()));
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            int keyHash = (key == null ? 0 : key.hashCode());
            int valueHash = (value == null ? 0 : value.hashCode());

            return keyHash ^ valueHash;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not valid to return `Iterator<ArrayMapEntry<K,V>>` from a method that is meant to return `Iterator<Entry<K, V>>`, even though on the surface it seems correct because `ArrayMapEntry` extends `Entry`.

Comment: However, it's just a raw stab. You didn't describe what is your actual problem here.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I just want to solve this problem and learn something about what should ```entrySet``` actually return and why this doesn't work, also, then how should I go around this?

Comment: You can read javadoc of the `entrySet()` to see what it's supposed to return. As for "this problem" - you speak like everyone knows what the problem is, yet you never actually said it.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I think the problem is that if I can't return the ```list.iterator()``` there, then what should I return?

Comment: For starters, a `Set` cannot contain duplicate values (by contract), whereas a `List` can. There should be measures to make sure your map has a valid `keySet()`. When implementing an `entrySet()`, that set contract with `keySet()` should not be broken also, which right now it does. Your actual problem is with this fact, not with simple type conundrum I pointed at earlier.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I know what a ```Set``` is, then I can just return something like ```new Hashset<>(entries)``` and it should be fine, right?

Comment: It might be fine, but defeats the point of having it called an "array map", since your actual structure is a `HashSet` then.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Then I really don't have any idea on how to about this